# Couldn't find the required information in the lock file. Make sure you have .NETCore,Version=v5.0/win10-anycpu mentioned in your targets

Tags: c#, winjs, win-universal-app

I'm working on a Windows 10 universal app. The aim was to have a JS front end connecting to a C# library for the heavy lifting. Though when I add the reference and trey to compile I get the following error

> Couldn't find the required information in the lock file. Make sure you
>   have .NETCore,Version=v5.0/win10-anycpu mentioned in your targets.

I've looked around and in a few cases the solution has been to update Visual Studio and the NuGet packages which I have done.

Any suggestions would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just change build configuration to x86 or ARM and it should work.

Any CPU is not supported by UWP projects, because they are built using .NET Native. You can read more about it [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/).